# Express - public server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, webserver

Use **Ubuntu**

Have Express app with *Hello world*. I wanna run app as public, setup static ip like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9fJWDoX4nE) video. It is my express server app:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var listener = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
  console.log(listener.address());// { address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 3000 }
});
```

I check my inet address with ifconfig command and get `192.168.0.102` - it is local IP address and when I enter `192.168.0.102:3000` I get *Hello world*. But when I try `194.242.103.139:3000` didn't have success. I am new with this stuff, please help and if you can with more details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `194.242.103.139` is your public IP address, make sure you have enabled route (port forwarding) on your router/gateway/firewall. Or put your machine IP to DMZ.

**Important** If you don't know what DMZ or port forwarding or anything mentioned above is, or what security risks this brings, please, don't mess up with your router. You would be asking for a nasty surprise. Read something on the topic of networking and security first.